# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string solution

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table in SQLServer

```
datetime                     tagname    value
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1290000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1280000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1280000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1280000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1280000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1280000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1280000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1280000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1280000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1280000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1280000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1280000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1280000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1280000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1280000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1280000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1280000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1280000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1280000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1280000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1280000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1280000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1280000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1280000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1280000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1280000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1280000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1280000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1280000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1270000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1260000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1250000 Weight_min  0
2018-02-02 09:06:24.1240000 Weight_min  0
```

and i am trying to run this code to query the value while conditioning the datetime column but i want to discard the time portion of it

```
select value from 
AnalogHistory 
where tagname = 'Weight_min' 
AND datetime between 
datediff(day, datetime, '2018-02-01 08:06:24.1290000' ) = 0
AND datediff(day, datetime, '2018-02-02 08:06:24.1290000' ) = 0
```

however it gives me Incorrect syntax near '='.

and when i tried to query only one date

```
select value from 
AnalogHistory 
where tagname = 'Weight_min' 
AND datediff(day, datetime, '2018-02-02 08:06:24.1290000' ) = 0
```

it gives me the above error
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I used this query before in a different table and it worked fine
any ideas ??

Comment: query makes no sense : "AND datetime between  ..."  that requires 2 dates not 2 integers

Comment: if it doesn't make sense it wouldn't have worked before ;)
this is to eliminate the time part in the datetime column

Comment: `AND datetime between 
datediff(day, datetime, '2018-02-01 08:06:24.1290000' ) = 0
AND datediff(day, datetime, '2018-02-02 08:06:24.1290000' ) = 0` is the equivalent of saying `AND datetime between 
true
AND true`, so @MitchWheat is correct when he says it doesn't make sense

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? If it's 2012 upwards you can convert your `datetime` value to a `date` data type which doesn't include the time component.

Comment: @MitchWheat wasn't trying to come across as that , apologies i was just wondering what was different, however thank you for trying to help
truly appreciated

Comment: If you're trying to do a query to "eliminate" the time part of a date, then `CAST(DateColumn AS date) = @Date`, `CONVERT(date, DateColumn) = @Date` and `DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0,DateColumn),0) = @Date` are not great ideas. Neither of these clauses are SARGable. Instead do something like `DateColumn >= @Date and DateColumn < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Date)`. That makes a SARGable `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Diado i am using SQL Server 2014

Comment: @Larnu thank you that worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

the answer from @Larnu in the comments worked for my scenario

> If you're trying to do a query to "eliminate" the time part of a date,
>   then `CAST(DateColumn AS date) = @Date`, `CONVERT(date, DateColumn) =@Date`
>   and `DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0,DateColumn),0) = @Date` are not
>   great ideas. Neither of these clauses are SARGable. Instead do
>   something like `DateColumn >= @Date and DateColumn < DATEADD(DAY, 1,@Date)`. That makes a SARGable `WHERE` clause